# Managing Deployed Packages - seeing how many are deployed, where, and what version they are on

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv

If we enroll in the ISV program, we will have access to create managed packages. When creating a managed package and listing them on the AppExchange, when the package gets downloaded, does Salesforce provide a tool/UI that will show you a comprehensive list of the Orgs that have downloaded your package and what version they are on so you can better manage your relationship with these orgs?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a capability provided by the LMA (License Management App). The LMA is documented in the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_intro.htm).

The LMA is installed in an org that you own, and populates data about your customers. See [Lead and License Records in the License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_terms_relationships.htm) in particular for details about how customer data is reflected into the LMA.

Comment: Got it - I didnt know that was also a piece of LMA! Thank you @David Reed